# how to update payload in mule esb

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I am getting a `iso8583` responce from server with some fields like `2,3,7,8` in `payload`. Now I want update a payload with second filed with different value. How can I do this in mule? I have tried to write a script in groovy but it is not executing..

this is my iso message (which is my payload):

```
ISO0160000751210B03080014E418000000000000000002897000000000000000000019916051912171405190620001809000000000614012837225UNI000000IDF331512135183102-0000001222358200-0000001222358200+0000000000000000+0000000000000000-0000001222358200INR              INR003FIG015117910100018219
```

Now i want to update the value in this payload. after parsing the payload it is split as a key value pair. If i use `payload.get(2)`, second field value will come but I want to update the second field value in payload. How please help me.

Comment: Can you post the flow you already have or a simplified version of it ? It will help in understanding the question and we can just update the existing to give you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the [Message Enricher](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/message-enricher), can be used as follows:

```
<enricher target="#[payload[2]]">
    <set-payload value="the new value to set"/>
</enricher>
```

This would set the value with key 2 in the map to what ever you define within the `set-payload` within the enricher. It is also possible to use multiple message processors within the enricher using `<processor-chain>`.